# To remove duplicate among array of objects corresponding to the other key and value pair of object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, keyvaluepair

Have an array of objects with object having two key and value pairs.

```
[{fruit:"apple",locale:"US"},
{fruit:"orange",locale:"US"},
{fruit:"banana",locale:"US"},
{fruit:"apple",locale:"US"},
{fruit:"orange",locale:"IT"},
{fruit:"apple",locale:"IT"},
{fruit:"banana",locale:"IT"},
{fruit:"orange",locale:"IT"}
{fruit:"apple",locale:"IT"}]
```

How to achieve
Fruit should not be duplicate within same locale,
Fruit can be same with different locales.

Comment: It might involve iterating over the array and storing a value like *fruit-locale*, then if you get a duplicate, splice it from the array. What have you tried?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the objects by matching the index value of current iteration. Something like this:

```js
var data=[{fruit:"apple",locale:"US"},{fruit:"orange",locale:"US"},{fruit:"banana",locale:"US"},{fruit:"apple",locale:"US"},{fruit:"orange",locale:"IT"},{fruit:"apple",locale:"IT"},{fruit:"banana",locale:"IT"},{fruit:"orange",locale:"IT"},{fruit:"apple",locale:"IT"}];

var result = data.filter((e,i,self)=>self.findIndex(k=>k.fruit==e.fruit && k.locale==e.locale)==i);

console.log(result);
```

Or you can make use of `Map`:

```js
var data=[{fruit:"apple",locale:"US"},{fruit:"orange",locale:"US"},{fruit:"banana",locale:"US"},{fruit:"apple",locale:"US"},{fruit:"orange",locale:"IT"},{fruit:"apple",locale:"IT"},{fruit:"banana",locale:"IT"},{fruit:"orange",locale:"IT"},{fruit:"apple",locale:"IT"}];

var result = [...new Map(data.map(k=>[`${k.fruit}|${k.locale}`, k])).values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
    obj = [{fruit:"apple",locale:"US"},
        {fruit:"orange",locale:"US"},
        {fruit:"banana",locale:"US"},
        {fruit:"apple",locale:"US"},
        {fruit:"orange",locale:"IT"},
        {fruit:"apple",locale:"IT"},
        {fruit:"banana",locale:"IT"},
        {fruit:"orange",locale:"IT"}
        {fruit:"apple",locale:"IT"}]

        const uniqueArray = this.obj.filter((item, index) => {
          const temp = JSON.stringify(item);
          return index === this.obj.findIndex(obj => {
          return JSON.stringify(obj) === temp;
          });
        });

        console.log(uniqueArray);
```